# Find the images of v and u under the composite of $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the following question:

> Let $V$ be a vector space, $v,u \in V$ and let $T_1: V \rightarrow V$ and
> $T_2: V \rightarrow V$ be linear transformations such that $$T_1(v) = 2 v  - 7 u, \ \ \ T_1(u) = -6 v + 2 u,$$ $$T_2(v) = -3 v  - 5 u, \ \ \ T_2(u) = -5 v + 3 u.$$
>
> Find the images of $v$ and $u$ under the composite of $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Am I not supposed to do
$$(T_2 T_1)(v) = T_2(T_1(v)) = -6v+16u$$
$$(T_2 T_1)(u) = T_2(T_1(u)) = -23v+6u$$

But this isn't the right answer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I figured it out 
$$(T_2 T_1)(v) = = T_2(T_1(v)) = T_2(2v - 7u) = 2*T_2(v) - 7*T_2(u)$$
And the similar reasoning for the other.

Answer (score 0):

$T_2(T_1(v)) = T_2(2v-7u)$

by linearity

$T_2(2v-7u) = 2T_2(v) - 7T_2(v) = -6v - 10u + 35v - 21u = 29v - 31u$.

And $T_2(T_1(u))$ is similar. :)